Assigning Users to a Company in Azure AD B2C
Currently have a working C# application that adds user to a B2C tenant which is excellent, but is there any way to separate them by company to ensure they sign in to the correct front end. Is this to do with User Flows, GraphAPI or both?
Originally I tried to set custom attributes but ultimately the users still all sit together in the same User list on the B2C which is not to the vision of the stakeholders.

Could you include more details like what you tried and where you stuck by editing your question with code and error?

There is no code or errors involved, all my users sit in one tenant and I'd simply like to know if it is possible to separate these users by the company they belong to or if they all must sit in that same list.

All the users in a B2C tenant are contained in one user "container".
If you want to physically split them. you need separate tenants which doesn't scale.
If you want to logically split them out, you can use e.g. groups or custom attributes. Custom policies is probably the way to go for this.

As I expected, thank you for this!

When you say that the users all sit in one user list on the B2C, it sounds like you are talking about the administrative interface for B2C.
Generally, the way you'd use B2C for a multi-tenant solution is to populate a custom attribute with some form of tenant identifier. You could use a company name, but generally you want something with more guaranteed uniqueness. Company name would merely be a cosmetic attribute of the tenant.
This custom attribute is what you can use to filter a user list in your application. The difference here is that typically you would build a user management front-end in the application, and one would not manage user accounts from the B2C admin interface directly unless something is going horribly wrong. I don't even think you can edit custom attributes from the B2C admin interface, but have to submit patch requests over the API.
If you need an administrative interface for back-end management that can access all tenants, but you still want to work per tenant, I think that's still a solution that would be built, interacting with B2C over the MS Graph API, rather than using the B2C admin interface. This could be done a couple ways - either the "super admins" are able to work as the tenant in question using the same interface the tenant account admin would use (like when they log in they can select which tenant to operate under), or you have an administrative backend application that essentially has god-view of the entire system, including all tenants.
But I think the bottom line is that the general pattern is to build your own administrative interface for multi-tenant applications and leave the B2C Azure admin blade alone, once it's configured and operating as expected.

Excellent Idea, thanks for replying I just needed clarification that Microsoft did not supply some formatting before I made my own.

But to just pick your brain again for one second, what if all the users in the tenant need to see different front ends based on their company? can this be done in that way?

I've used a framework called Finbuckle.Multitenant to help bootstrap this. Essentially, you'll need a tenant identifier held in the B2C as a custom attribute for each user. This value will be pulled down with the JWT as a user claim after the user successfully logs in. At the point where your application "starts" for the logged-in user, you'll need to evaluate the tenant identifier in the user claims collection and base everything that happens in the application on that piece of information (tenant-specific connection string, etc).
